# How to improve performance on nested graphql connections when using pagination

Tags: postgresql, graphql, apollo, typeorm, dataloader

I'm trying to implement some kind of a basic social network project. It has `Posts`, `Comments` and `Likes` like any other.

- A post can have many comments
- A post can have many likes
- A post can have one author

I have a `/posts` route on the client application. It lists the `Posts` by paginating and shows their `title`, `image`, `authorName`, `commentCount` and `likesCount`.

The `graphql` query is like this;

```
query {
  posts(first: 10, after: "123456") {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        imageUrl
        author {
          id
          username
        }
        comments {
          totalCount
        }
        likes {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using `apollo-server`, `TypeORM`, `PostgreSQL` and `dataloader`. I use `dataloader` to get `author` of each post. I simply batch the requested `authorIds` with `dataloader`, get `authors` from `PostgreSQL` with a `where user.id in authorIds` query, map the query result to the each `authorId`. You know, the most basic type of usage of `dataloader`.

But when I try to query the `comments` or `likes` connection under each `post`, I got stuck. I could use the same technique and use `postId` for them if there was no pagination. But now I have to include filter parameters for the pagination. And there maybe other filter parameters for some `where` condition as well.

I've found the `cacheKeyFn` option of dataloader. I simply create a string key for the passed filter object to the dataloader, and it doesn't duplicate them. It just passes the unique ones to the `batchFn`. But I can't create a sql query with `TypeORM` to get the results for each `first`, `after`, `orderBy` arguments separately and map the results back to the function which called the dataloader.

I've searched the `spectrum.chat` source code and I think they don't allow users to query nested connections. Also tried Github GraphQL Explorer and it lets you query nested connections.

Is there any recommended way to achieve this? I understood how to pass an `object` to `dataloader` and batch them using `cacheKeyFn`, but I can't figure out how to get the results from `PostgreSQL` in one query and map the results to return from the loader.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Onur Önder, have you managed to get a doable solution to this problem? Do you have a sample public repository? It would help me a lot! Maybe you can also check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089839

Comment: I've used a simple solution and I see that it works for me now. You can find an example here: https://github.com/onderonur/post-gallery/blob/master/api/src/db/entity/Comment.ts#L80
I did not have time to explain it in a clear way, sorry. But I also told the steps in comments of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244734/10876256
I would hope there would be a simpler solution for this. Creating the same structure for each connection is a little time consuming. But I think I've found a solution at least :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, if you restrict things a bit, this is doable. The restriction is to only allowed batched connections on the first page of results, e.g. so all the connections you're fetching in parallel are being done with the parameters. This is a reasonable constraint because it lets you do things like get the first 10 feed items and the first 3 comments for each of them, which represents a fairly typical use case. Trying to support independent pagination within a single query is unlikely to fulfil any real world use cases for a UI, so it's likely an over-optimisation. With this in mind, you can support the "for each parent get the first N children" use case with PostgreSQL using window.

It's a bit fiddly, but there are answers floating around which will get you in the right direction: [Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group)

So use dateloader how you are with `cacheKeyFn`, and let your loader function recognise whether you can perform the optimisation (e.g. after is `null` and all other arguments are the same). If you can optimise, use a windowing query, otherwise do unoptimised queries in parallel as you would normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I've actually trying something by using UNION ALL and it seems like it works for me.
I've been able to fetch different type of pagination results with unrelated arguments and map those back to the "callers" of the dataloader. And it's just 1 DB hit for each new nested connection level. I think it is fairly good for GraphQL perspective.
It's a little bit verbose for now and I'm not sure if it's working 100%. I will experiment a little bit more and share my findings.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ah yeah, unions queries will work, but make sure you check the performance of the different approaches.